# problem saving an array of strings to a file in C

Tags: arrays, c, file

The following code is supposed to save my_data[] to a file called data.txt. however it only saves the first element. In this case the word "this".
What I really want to do is save whole multidimensional arrays in a way that other programs can access any individual element using standard array mining terminology.
PS Im sure that a .txt file is not the ideal file format, what is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char my_data[2][2] = {"this","is","a" ,"test"};
    char path[] = "C:\\Users\\dave\\Documents\\data.txt";        
    
      FILE *fp ;

          if ((fp = fopen(path,"w+")) == NULL)
                {
                printf("cannot open file");
                exit(1);
                }

      fwrite(my_data, sizeof(char), sizeof(my_data), fp);

      rewind(fp);

      fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: What is the value of `sizeof(my_data)`

Comment: The compiler should be complaining about the code you show. How many characters is there in the string `"this"`? How many elements do you initialize the array with?

Comment: How many bytes does the string `"this"` use in memory? How many strings are there in `{"this","is","a" ,"test"}`?

Comment: Should the resulting file be a text file? If yes, then how exactly should the text file look like?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up your array properly, and then loop through each individual string in the array, using a `for` loop.

For example:

```
int count = 12

char* months[] = {
  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
};  

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  printf("%s\n", months[i]);
}
```

You probably won't be able to use `sizeof` for this, since each string can vary in length.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char my_data[4][5] = { "this","is","a" ,"test" };
  // 4: because we have 4 strings
  // 5: because the longest string is 4 letters and +1 for the NUL string terminator
  char path[] = "data.txt";

  printf("Content of my_data\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("read_data[][i] = %s\n", my_data[i]);

  FILE* fp;

  if ((fp = fopen(path, "wb")) == NULL)
  {
    printf("cannot open file");
    exit(1);
  }

  int byteswritten = fwrite(my_data, sizeof(char), sizeof(my_data), fp);
  fclose(fp);
  printf("%d bytes written\n", byteswritten);

  char read_data[4][5];

  if ((fp = fopen(path, "rb")) == NULL)
  {
    printf("cannot open file");
    exit(1);
  }

  int bytesread = fread(read_data, sizeof(char), sizeof(read_data), fp);
  printf("%d bytes read\n", byteswritten);

  printf("Content of read_data\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("read_data[][i] = %s\n", read_data[i]);

  fclose(fp);
}
```

The program writes the raw bytes of `my_data` into the `data.txt` file (which is not a text file BTW).

Then it reads these same raw bytes into `read_data` which is declared exactly the same way as `my_data`. This also works if the read part is in an other program.

This only works if both `my_data` and `read_data` are declared with the exact same sizes.